# spring data mongodb auditing not work when bulk insert

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm currently use spring data mongodb 1.10.9.RELEASE which import by spring boot starter data mongodb 1.5.9.

When add @EnableMongoAuditing on my Configuration class and use function save of CrudRepository, my createdTime been set transparently.

But when i use bulk.insert it's not work any more.I found bulk.insert not send BeforeConvertEvent and AuditingEventListener's onApplicationEvent(BeforeConvertEvent event) not called.so my createdTime have not been set.

So is this is a bug or intentionally or my found is wrong?

This is my simple code(not set createdTime ):

```
private void save(List<byte[]> msgs, Class clazz) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(msgs))
            return ;
        BulkOperations bulk = template.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, clazz);

        for (byte[] value : msgs) {
           bulk.insert(JSONUtil.readValue(value, clazz););
        }

        bulk.execute();
}
```

Comment: can you update the stack log, for checking the error messages?

Comment: Bulkoperations does not emit event hence auditing will not work, this is intentionally written in this way in Spring data mongodb

Comment: @Sunand Padmanabhan Could you explain why? And if I want my createdTime be set in bulk insert, how can I impl?

Comment: @saif ali There is no error msg or any log, because this is not a error, just only do not send event and trigger appropriate function.

Comment: Is there any workaround besides manually setting those fields? That makes the entire MongoAuditing component redundant if one uses only bulk ops

Comment: @Gilad Peleg You are right, but there is no other way to set those fields for me. If you find, please tell me.

Comment: @MallenHuang Did you find any better solution??

Comment: @PKR Sorry，@Sunand Padmanabhan tell me Spring data mongodb do this intentionally. So,I think you can do nothing except set it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/1797) explained why the audit data was not populated:

> Auditing is applied only when working with entities directly via IsNewAwareAuditingHandler and not for query-based/bulk updates. Query-based updates require an association to an entity type, updates using just a collection name cannot participate in auditing updates

MongoTemplate does not have a method of bulk updating directly a list of entities so we have to save one by one entity to have audit data which leads to performance loss. It did so many round trips from our application to the database.

To leverage bulk update with good performance and have our audit data, it can be done by following way which does not require much changes:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.bson.Document;
import your.auditable.entity.MyEntity;

......

private Update convertToAuditableUpdateDocument(MyEntity entity)
    Document updateDoc = new Document();
    mongoConverter.write(entity, updateDoc);
    return Update.fromDocument(updateDoc)
            // for populating auditable data using bulk / query-based updates
            .set("lastModifiedBy", auditor)
            .set("lastModifiedDate", ZonedDateTime.now())
            .setOnInsert("createdBy", auditor)
            .setOnInsert("createdDate", ZonedDateTime.now());
}

....

private void bulkUpsertEntities(MongoTemplate template, List<Pair<Query, Update>> bulkUpsertList) {
    template.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, MyEntity.class)
              .upsert(bulkUpsertList)
              .execute();
}
```

Then you will see your audit data populated as expected.

[Audit data was populated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrzXh.png)

NOTE: Tested with ~ 890 entities, the executing time reduced from 7 seconds to 0.5 seconds by using bulk update.